# I have a project in Phaser. I want to do a user image editor on elements on the canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, phaser-framework

The user have a menu of items (let's call them stickers) and he place them on the stage.

I want them to be able to edit them (scale and rotation), but I don't want it to be a toolbar but a display on the element itself.

I found what I need but it's on [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events).

Can I use that code on Phaser, or is there a library that does the same thing for Phaser?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such functionality readily available in Phaser. You'll have to write it yourself.

A good starting point (or at least how I would do it) would be a custom class that extends `Phaser.Group` and contains the image itself (possibly as a sprite) and the helper sprites (let's call them "handles") that are laid around. A `Phaser.Group` can have its own `update()`, so you can deal with the handle input there. It comes naturally that you should modify both `scale.x` and `scale.y` of the sprite when dragging any corner handle or respectively only `x` or `y` when dragging by any of the sides. You'll have to deal with the anchors and position by yourself.